# Create new object from nested resources for the new action method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose I have this association:

```
class User < ActiveRecord :: Base
  has_one :car
end
class Car < ActiveRecord :: Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

routes:

```
resources :users do
  resources :cars
end
```

Then what would be the code, in the 'new' action method in CarsController

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    #??? what's necessary to be put here, 
    # if I have request 'localhost:3000/users/1/cars/new'
  end
  ...
end
```

Will Rails figure out everything automatically so I don't have to write any code in the 'new' method? Also, since the 'new' action will generate a 'form_for(@car)' form helper, how can I create this car object

Is this right?

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @car = @user.build_car({})
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

That looks just fine. Rails will *not* do any of this automatically. There are gems out there that can automate some of that if you like, but the jury is out on whether they're actually worth your time.

If you have no params to pass to the car, you can just run `@user.build_car` with no arguments, by the way. You'll also need to specifically say in the `form_for` helper that you're nesting the car under the user: `form_for [@user, @car]` Otherwise the form's destination will be `/cars` instead of `/user/1/cars`.

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close, Baboon. 
I would actually do:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.new
    @car = @user.cars.build
  end
end
```

But if you don't want to create the Car at the same time as the user, try:

```
class CarsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @car = @user.cars.build
  end
end
```

I found the nested_form railscast extremely helpful when doing this sort of thing. In fact, I think you'll probably get a lot out of it (and using the nested_form gem).

[railscasts_196-nested-model-form-part-1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)